# Regex string does not contain?

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to create a **regex** which finds a text that contains :

1. `src`
2. `.js`

and does not contain a question mark '?' at the same time.

For example I want my regex to match :

```
src="scripts/test.js"
```

and not match :

```
src="Servlet?Template=scripts/test.js"
```

because it contains a question mark sign.

Can anyone give me the appropriate **regex**?

Thanks a lot

Comment: This is one of those times when I would probably prefer to read `if (str.indexOf('src') !== -1 && str.indexOf('.js') !== -1 && str.indexOf('?') === -1) { ... }`.

Comment: I wish I can use it ,but I'm dealing with a full template text so it might contain several occurrences  of 'src' with '.js' and I want to alter each occurrence of src

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex:

```
/\bsrc=(?!.*?\?).+?\.js\b/i
```

`(?!.*?\?)` is negative lookahead that means fail the match when there is a `?` following `src=` in input string.

Comment: thank you ! I tried it but it passed this text <script language="JavaScript" src="apps/core/scripts/frameset/buttons.js"></script>

Comment: Of course it did. Your specification asked for it to match that.

Comment: @user2484927: Why it should not match `<script language="JavaScript" src="apps/core/scripts/frameset/buttons.js"></script>` ?

Comment: what I meant is that it didn't match this sentence

Comment: I want my test to match this type of sentence so I can alter it

Comment: @user2484927 Are you after something like [this](https://regex101.com/r/nC3wH4/2) that gets a capture of the string inside the `src` attribute?

Comment: I'm using in Java , Pattern and Matcher classes : `Pattern p= Pattern.compile("/=\\bsrc=(?!.*?\\?).+?\\.js\\b");
                    
Matcher m= p.matcher(strTemplateText); ` `m.find()` is returning false even though strTemplatetext contains `<script language="JavaScript" src="apps/core/scripts/frameset/buttons.js"></script>` @anubhava @Phylogenesis

Comment: Java‽ The tag in your question says JavaScript. They are completely different languages.

Comment: @user2484927: Huh your question was tagged as `Javascript`. In Java it will be: `Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\bsrc=(?!.*?\\?).+?\\.js\\b");`

Comment: sorry ! I should have tagged java instead of javascript . It works now but I need to replace `<script language="JavaScript" src="apps/core/scripts/frameset/buttons.js"></script>` with `<script language="JavaScript" src="apps/core/scripts/frameset/buttons.js?Id=${id}"></script>` Can you help?

Comment: You can use: **`String repl = input.replaceFirst("(\\bsrc=(?!.*?\\?).+?\\.js\\b)", "$1?Id=${id}");`**

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be wanting to [parse/make changes to HTML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags), but since you're using JavaScript, you already have a fully functional DOM parser available to you.

How about the following:

```
var scripts = document.querySelectorAll('script[src]');

for (var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) {
    var src = scripts[i].getAttribute('src');

    if (/\.js$/.test(src) && src.indexOf('?') === -1) {
        alert(src);
    }
}
```

Example jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/13Leon90/).